# GM_getValue is causing a "deprecated" warning?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I saved a value using `GM_setValue` in a script using

```
GM_setValue ("foo", "bar");
```

A database is created - "save.db"

This is what I'm doing to read/alert the value of "foo" back using `GM_getValue`:

```
// @grant GM_setValue
// @grant GM_getValue
// ==/UserScript==

var temp ;
temp = GM_log(GM_getValue("foo"));
alert(temp);
```

But, I got a Warning in the Error Console:

> Warning: Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated. Use
>   WeakMap or element.dataset instead.

If the stored value can't be read this way, what's the correct way of retrieving the value of "foo" back?

Answer (score 1):

**[Greasemonkey does not even use `getUserData`.](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/search?q=getUserData&type=Code)**

That error is not being caused by Greasemonkey. It is being caused by another extension -- probably AdBlock Plus. [AdBlock Plus is known to have this problem](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=749981#c3).

You can tell which extension, or web-page code, is causing the problem by checking Firefox's error console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>).
Hover over the source link, on the right-hand side, or click the link to open the offending file. :
[image: The error console shows where the error came from]

The underlined part is the unique ID for AdBlock Plus.  Every Firefox extension has a unique ID.  Greasemonkey's is `{e4a8a97b-f2ed-450b-b12d-ee082ba24781}.xpi`